# sending arbitrary request data in Django

Tags: python, django

While not a noobie to Python I am to Django.  I have started to build an app that takes information from the form and queries network devices via REST.  I get the data from the form just fine.  The data gets passed to the proper module, Device_build_test as defined in my view.  When that module gets the requested data, how do I get that into the template qa_results.html?  My view for the form looks like so:
    def device_qa_build( request):

```
if request.method == 'POST':
    form = Device_qa_Form(request.POST )
    if form.is_valid():
      cd = form.cleaned_data

      Device_build_test.set_up(
        cd
     )
    return HttpResponseRedirect('/qa_results.html/')
else:
    form = Device_qa_Form()

return render_to_response('device_qa_build_form.html', {'form':form} )
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use function `render_to_response`, like what you didi to `device_qa_build_form.html` in your code.

You will have to modify `qa_results.html` to give it a variable called `form`, then using `render_to_response`. Something like this:

```
if request.method == 'POST':
    form = Device_qa_Form(request.POST )
    if form.is_valid():
      cd = form.cleaned_data

      Device_build_test.set_up(
        cd
     )
    # return HttpResponseRedirect('/qa_results.html/')
    return render_to_response('/qa_results.html/', {'form':form})
else:
    form = Device_qa_Form()

return render_to_response('device_qa_build_form.html', {'form':form} )
```

Here is instruction of render_to_response for you.
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/http/shortcuts/

Answer (score 0):

I got it to work this way... getting the  returned data and creating the context sending it on. If anyone thinks this is a bad idea let me know.

```
 if request.method == 'POST':
    form = Device_qa_Form(request.POST )
    if form.is_valid():
      cd = form.cleaned_data

      results = Device_build_test.set_up(
        cd
     )
     t = loader.get_template('qa_results.html')
     c = Context({'results':results})
     return HttpResponse( t.render(c))
 else:
    form = Device_qa_Form()

return render_to_response('device_qa_build_form.html', {'form':form} )
```